# MobileFirst: At Public IP- Unable to Call adapter from application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

On Production I am receiving the error below.

> POST http://publicIP:9080/AppName/apps/services/api/proj/common/query
>   403 (Forbidden ( The server denied the specified Uniform Resource
>   Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator.  ))worklight.js:1099
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.requestworklight.js:1062
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.initializeworklight.js:526
>   klassworklight.js:3410
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.sendRequestworklight.js:3278
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.initializeworklight.js:526
>   klassworklight.js:8580 __invokeProcedureworklight.js:8623 (anonymous
>   function) worklight.js:5061
>   [/AppName/apps/services/api/AppName/common/query] failure. state: 403,
>   response: The server was unable to process the request from the
>   application. Please try again later.worklight.js:5061
>   WL.Logger.__logworklight.js:5445 PUBLIC_API.(anonymous
>   function)worklight.js:3559
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onFailureworklight.js:3522
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlFailureworklight.js:958
>   (anonymous function)worklight.js:1181
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyStateworklight.js:1114
>   window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChangeworklight.js:958
>   (anonymous function)

I am using

- IBM MobileFirst 6.3 Consumer Edition
- Liberty profile 8.5.3

Scenarios Run
This App is running on Localhost and within internal Network perfectly well.
But at Public IP, I am unable to access the httpadapter from Application.

//********ERROR Browser LoG On Calling App

> Blockquote

Denied Connection
INTERNALTMG 2/26/2015 1:43:12 PM
Log type: Web Proxy (Reverse)
Status: 12202 Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).
Rule: mobileapps
Source: Internal (10.39.30.64:52151)
Destination: Local Host (worklightsvr.local.machine 132.20.68.46:9080)
Request: POST http://132.20.68.46:9080/AppName/apps/services/api/example/common/query
Filter information: Req ID: 0a68784f; Compression: client=Yes, server=No, compress rate=0% decompress rate=0%
Protocol: http
User: anonymous
Description: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway\UI_HTMLs_image\general\minusImg.gifAdditional information
1.                 Client agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
2.     Object source: Internet (Source is the Internet. Object was added to the cache.)
3.     Cache info: 0x51c0000 (Response includes the CACHE-CONTROL: NO-CACHE or PRAGMA: NO-CACHE header. Response includes the CACHE-CONTROL: NO-STORE header. Response includes either the CACHE-CONTROL: MUST-REVALIDATE or CACHE-CONTROL: PROXY-REVALIDATE header. Response includes the EXPIRES header. Response includes the WWW-AUTHENTICATE header.)
4.                  Processing time: 1 MIME type:

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, verify with your IT department that you are not blocking the URL/domain somewhere in your corporate firewall.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Let me tell you the exact log tread

Comment: Dear Idan- I have edit my question. please do have a look and our answer would be needful here

Comment: Please read the error log you've posted. Consult with your IT department.

Comment: I have consulted with IT Depart. They have created rule to enable all the urls from public to access WL Server. They are now asking for the URL of the request actually calling from WL App to Adapter.

Comment: for any reason, could that be an issue from development & configuration side?

Comment: Any Updates? on my request

Comment: We have cross checked with the TMG server. But every URL has been assigned and enable in Rule(s). worklight/*, application/*, AppName/*

Comment: If every URL has been enables and assigned as accessible. what would be the cause then? NEED HELP!

Comment: If you require help and you are an IBM customer - open a PMR. Stack Overflow is a Community website and you get no guarantee for immediate help.